# Free online charting services?

Tags: image, charts

I am looking for a service, similar to the deprecated Google image charting API.
I need to create graphs and send them via email. Therefore it's important that the
resulting chart will be an image (and not some kind of interactive javascript object).
The service also needs to be free.

Do you know of any such service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know such API but here is how I could proceed, I'd use [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) to generate piture from the graph if I wanted to do canvas based drawing.

Here is an [article](http://thechangelog.com/post/1489735759/node-canvas-render-and-stream-html5-canvas-using-node-js) about it.

If I wanted to use a SVG library like [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) I would use [phamtomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to [generate](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering) the picture from the SVG canvas.

Comment: Cool tip about phantomjs. Do u know of any server side alternative written in .net?

Comment: Nop, PhantomJS is quite unique as far as I know at least in the UNIX world. Sorry I despise the windos world. Phantom is not so much fun to play with as it is non verbose error-wise. But it can do incredible things. You could make our own app in phamtomJS and host it on a PAAS like dotcloud for example.